# Why Android Emulator receiving SIGTRAP after int 3 instruction?

Tags: android, debugging, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I am using IDA 7.5 and Android Emulator ( I tried many version of emulator, like BlueStack etc) trying to debug a native code inside a apk (`.so` file ).

Launch apk, IDA select remote linux debugger ( most of Android Emulator are x86 image. ), attach to process

Let's say there's two threads that are about to execute to the address of `0x123`.

And I set a breakpoint in `0x123`, click execute, thread A hit breakpoint as expected. ( its `eip` shows `0x123` ). But switch to thread B I found that it is stop at `0x124` ( it's `eip` shows `0x124` ). And if I trying to continue executing thread B, IDA report thread B receiving `SIGTRAP` at `0x124`.

AFAIK, IDA debug a program by inserting a `int 3` instruction. But somehow thread B execute report `SIGTRAP` after executing `int 3`.

---

At this point I thought it maybe some strange behavior of Android Emulator. So I tried using GDBSERVER + GDB to reproduce this situation. But every thing works fine.
Then I thought it maybe some issue with IDA's `remote linux debugger`, so I select IDA's `remote gdb debugger` instead.

But the same issue occur to me.

---

I also tried IDA's remote debugger with real device and nothing went wrong

---

Is there anyone familiar with IDA's debugger implementation that can give me some advices. plz.